# How to avoid CryptographicException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, cryptographicexception

You receive a System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException when a decryption fails because the key is wrong.
How does one avoid it? Is there a built-in solution that preferably looks like this?

```
if (someClass.TryDecrypt(encrypted key, out var result)) {
    //use result
}
else {
    //fail like the world hasn't ended yet.
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just `catch` the exception?

Comment: @KlausGütter Because I don't want to catch 40k exceptions/second?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle this situation is to `catch` the exception.

If your code is referred to a server-side environment, and you want to mitigate the risk of crashing your server because of the considerable amount of requests that may income (e.g. DoS), you might set an interval between the requests incoming from the same IP Address, for example.